# Send a custom email from sonata admin using variables

Tags: symfony, listview, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I have a list view in sonata admin. I want to add a column that will allow me to click on a link to send an email. The link action will know variables from that row in the table so that it can fill in the email. I was able to add the column and can visualize a twig template. I've added the following function to the Admin Class:

```
 public function sendEmail( \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('some email'))
            ->setFrom('contact@example.com')
            ->setTo('contact@example.com')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'emails/response.html.twig',
                    array('manufacturer' => $manuvalue, 'modelnum' => $modelnumvalue, 'email' => $email)
                ),
                'text/html');

        $mailer->send($message);

    }
```

I'm stuck on how to connect these pieces together so that when I click on the link the email is sent and includes the params from the row. I have email working on form submit in other areas of the site, but need help figuring out the way to do this manually.

Comment: What I would do is have the link connected to a route which takes the params and where you call this function.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber Would it technically be considered a custom Admin action as highlighted here? https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html  I know how to this with a public route, but haven't done this on the Admin side and want to make sure it is behind the Auth of Admin.

Comment: I am not really sure because I am not familiar with the Sonata Admin bundle. However, you could also just have it as a regular route and use the symfony security component to give access to that route. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html. What I do is just add it in the annotation of the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a custom route and protected it with security settings that @dirk mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, what you want to do is typically a [Custom Action](https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html)

In order to ensure that this action can not be accessed via direct request and can only be performed by admin, you could do use a template like this for your customAction :

```
...
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
...

//AuthorizationCheckerInterface injected as authorizationChecker

public function customAction($id){
    $object = $this->admin->getSubject();
    if (!$object) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id: %s', $id));
    }

    // Check access with role of your choice
    $access = $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
    if($access){

    //Do your action

    } else {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException("You don't have the rights to do that!");
    }
}
```